# Есть ли возможность бесплатно использовать легальное ПО?

Tags: dreamspark

Долго спорил со своими студентами по поводу использования легального софта. Большинство озвучило, на мой взгляд, вполне адекватную мысль: «Как бы слишком дофига денег это стоит для меня, студента».

Использовали ли вы легальный софт бесплатно? Пользовались ли возможностями DreamsPark? Какие есть нюансы при регистрации на сайте?

Comment: Не всякий легальный софт - это DreamSpark, и не всякий легальный софт платный.

Исходя из этого - да, используйте Линукс - бесплатно и легально (есть конечно и платные линуксы (за поддержку), но это для большого бизнеса).

Comment: а взять и зарегистрироваться никак?
Это тяжело? Быстрее было бы начать регистрироваться чем ждать ответа здесь!

Comment: 2 Shrek: Конечно, можно и нужно зарегистрироваться. Уверен, что тема со студентами еще поднимется, поэтому хочу чьи-нибудь комментарии получить. Может Вы сами пользуетесь ПО по DreamSpark?

2 KoVadim: Ну вот зацепили мы в разговоре со студентами проект DreamSpark, поэтому интересуюсь именно этим вариантом. И да, все-таки интересует Windows.

Comment: @z-ziba

тогда в своем вопросе правильно и пишите и не вводите людей в заблуждение!

> Есть ли возможность бесплатно использовать легальное ПО?

заменить на 

Есть ли возможность бесплатно использовать легальное ПО от Майкрософта, не смотря на его качество?


И если адекватные мысли студентов включают не совсем деловую лексику, то видимо им побоку на легальность.

Comment: да нет у этого пиджака ни каких студентов. зато есть зарплата от MS. удалите спам пожалуйста.

http://www.programmersforum.ru/search.php?searchid=1472208
http://www.sql.ru/forum/memberinfo.aspx?mid=204039
http://forum.codeby.net/topic52289s0.html?p=242392&#entry242392

Answer (score 4):

Хотел бы озвучить две мысли. Для начала скажу, что DreamSpark'ом не пользовался, но думаю, особых проблем с регистрацией вряд ли стоит опасаться. Впрочем, я не об этом.

Необходимое уточнение: все, что будет сказано ниже, относится к средствам разработки. Я беру на себя наглость  полагать, что вы задаете вопрос на форуме программистов именно о ПО подобного рода.

1. Если речь идет о средствах разработки Microsoft (коль скоро вы заговорили про DreamSpark) В 99,9% случаев студенту для выполнения его задач с головой достаточно экпресс-версий  майкрософтовских продуктов. С трудом себе представляю задачи студента, в которых ему потребовалось бы что-то. не входящее в Exprress-редакцию. Разве что без сторонних плагинов вроде Resharper'a работать не столь удобно
2. Если речь о ПО других компаний. Рынок кишит бесплатными инструментами разработки. Начиная от "детского" PascalABC и заканчивая более чем "взрослыми" Eclipse, Intellij Idea. Также можно обратить внимание на проект Mono. Причем подобное разнообразие есть не только среди IDE, но и прочих необходимых для разработчика инструментов.

То есть все вышесказанное имеет в себе следующую мораль - даже если по каким-то причинам не срастется с DreamSpark (скажем, все ваши студенты потеряют свои студенческие билеты) есть куча выходов и помимо этой программы

Comment: "все ваши студенты потеряют свои студенческие билеты"

Возня с документами, узнавал, уже необязательна. Зарегистрироваться можно и через аккаунт в ВКонтакте.

Comment: Ну тем лучше. А что за ПО вам вообще нужно, если не секрет? И что преподаете?

Answer (score 2):

Пользовался и пользуюсь dreamspark. Регаться можно как с помощью отправки студ. билета так и просто введя код (майкрософтовцы частенько раздают их на встречах всяких). Не понимаю только, зачем об этом было здесь спрашивать?

+если Вы от университета, то можете зарегатсья как учреждение и тогда всему ВУЗу дадут dreamspark premium. Там и софта побольше и появляется он раньше (к примеру win8.1 уже давно там. Т. е. практически тоже, что и msdn подписка)

Comment: "Регаться можно как с помощью отправки студ. билета"

Правила регистрации упростились. Теперь ничего отправлять не нужно, можно зарегистрироваться просто через свою страницу в ВКонтакте.